# Mount ext4 with UUID in /etc/fstab

Tags: fstab, automounting

I'm trying to mount USB thumb drive to my router.

My USB thumb drive is 32GB,divided to two partitions :
16GB NTFS and  16GB ext4 .

The 16GB NTFS partition will be automatically detected in router as  sda1 and by default mounted to /mnt/sda1 and /tmp/ftp/Volume_A1.

The 16GB ext4 automatically detected in router as sda2 but has not been mounted.

So I want to mount sda2 to /test

these what I did:

1. `mount /dev/sda2  /test`  <======  sda2 will be mounted to /test, but gone after router rebooted
2. added the UUID of `/dev/sda2` as below  to `/etc/fstab` to mount it on `/test`
   .<========== I check on `df`  never been mounted , please see below

```
root@router:/# blkid
/dev/sda2: UUID="14a0f0f0-27ac-4101-8d11-3057f10d1385" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="usbdata" UUID="23D9FBBC72AB064E" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/ubi1_0: UUID="9c7f4c41-289f-4c49-8036-3698b24c7687" TYPE="ubifs"
/dev/ubi0_0: UUID="66fa53a5-cc19-454d-b1a4-6a691051fb9e" TYPE="ubifs"
```

I added the UUID of `/dev/sda2` (listed above) to `/etc/fstab` to mount it on `/test`:

```
root@router:/# nano /etc/fstab 

# fstab file - used to mount file systems
proc            /proc                proc       defaults                        0   0
tmpfs           /var                 tmpfs      size=420k,noexec                0   0
tmpfs           /mnt                 tmpfs      size=16k,noexec                 0   0
tmpfs           /dev                 tmpfs      size=64k,mode=0755,noexec       0   0
sysfs           /sys                 sysfs      defaults                        0   0

debugfs         /sys/kernel/debug    debugfs    nofail                          0   0

mtd:bootfs      /bootfs              jffs2      ro                              0   0
UUID=14a0f0f0-27ac-4101-8d11-3057f10d1385  /test   auto   nosuid,nodev,nofail   0   0
```

```
root@router:/# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
ubi:rootfs_ubifs         44840     38760      6080  86% /
mtd:bootfs                4480      3440      1040  77% /bootfs
mtd:data                  4096       464      3632  11% /data
ubi1:tp_data              4584       844      3472  20% /tp_data
ubi:rootfs_ubifs         44840     38760      6080  86% /tmp/root
/dev/sda1             15452156     84620  15367536   1% /mnt/sda1
/dev/sda1             15452156     84620  15367536   1% /tmp/ftp/Volume_A1
```

<sup>[Spacing has been modified in an attempt to increase readability.]</sup>

Please advise and thank you

===========================================================================

Following up comment's below :

===========================================================================

As [suggested by Aaron D. Marasco](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/600768/80216#comment1121771_600768), I changed `auto` to `ext4`:

```
UUID=14a0f0f0-27ac-4101-8d11-3057f10d1385  /test   ext4   nosuid,nodev,nofail   0   0
```

still no luck. `df` as same result as before

And here is the output from `ps`, [as requested by Hauke Laging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/600768/80216#comment1121906_600768). 
(The  router's Busybox doesn’t recognize the `-p` option.)

```
root@router:/# ps -o pid,args

PID   COMMAND
    1 init
    2 [kthreadd]
    3 [ksoftirqd/0]
    4 [kworker/0:0]
    5 [kworker/0:0H]
    6 [kworker/u4:0]
    7 [rcu_preempt]
    8 [rcu_sched]
    9 [rcu_bh]
   10 [migration/0]
   11 [migration/1]
   12 [ksoftirqd/1]
   14 [kworker/1:0H]
   15 [khelper]
  122 [writeback]
  125 [ksmd]
  126 [crypto]
  127 [bioset]
  129 [kblockd]
  151 [skbFreeTask]
  152 [bcmFapDrv]
  173 [kswapd0]
  174 [fsnotify_mark]
  294 [cfinteractive]
  344 [kworker/1:1]
  351 [linkwatch]
  352 [ipv6_addrconf]
  357 [deferwq]
  362 [ubi_bgt0d]
  926 [jffs2_gcd_mtd2]
  947 [ubi_bgt1d]
  962 [ubifs_bgt1_0]
 1039 [bcmFlwStatsTask]
 1113 [kworker/1:2]
 1137 {rcS} /bin/sh /etc/init.d/rcS S boot
 1139 init
 1140 logger -s -p 6 -t sysinit
 1286 /sbin/klogd
 1540 /sbin/hotplug2 --override --persistent --set-rules-file /etc/hotplug2.rul
 1550 /usr/sbin/logd -C 128
 1555 /sbin/ubusd
 1558 {S12ledctrl} /bin/sh /etc/rc.common /etc/rc.d/S12ledctrl boot
 1560 /usr/bin/ledctrl
 1627 [bcmsw_rx]
 1629 [bcmsw]
 1636 [pdc_rx]
 1649 /bin/swmdk
 1766 /sbin/netifd
 4265 [dhd_watchdog_th]
 4272 [wfd0-thrd]
 4425 [check_task]
 4493 [kworker/0:2]
 4559 [scsi_eh_0]
 4562 [scsi_tmf_0]
 4568 [usb-storage]
 4917 [kworker/u4:2]
 4919 [kworker/1:1H]
 5039 /usr/sbin/imbd
 5207 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -C /var/etc/dnsmasq.conf
 5219 [ telnetDBGD ]
 5220 [ acktelnetDBGD ]
 5243 [NU TCP]
 5248 [NU UDP]
 5356 eapd
 5369 nas
 5395 wps_monitor
 6095 acsd
 7008 /usr/sbin/mcud
 7592 /usr/sbin/dropbear -P /var/run/dropbear.1.pid -p 22
 7598 {S50postcenter} /bin/sh /etc/rc.common /etc/rc.d/S50postcenter boot
 7600 /usr/sbin/postcenter
 7612 /usr/sbin/sysmond
 7620 {S50tmpServer} /bin/sh /etc/rc.common /etc/rc.d/S50tmpServer boot
 7622 /usr/bin/tmpServer
 7626 /usr/sbin/tsched
 7628 /usr/bin/tmpServer
 7777 /usr/bin/client_mgmt
 8350 /usr/sbin/ntpd -n -p time.nist.gov -p time-nw.nist.gov -p time-a.nist.gov
 8398 [ubifs_bgt0_0]
 8403 /usr/bin/cloud-https
 8639 {S99switch_led} /bin/sh /etc/rc.common /etc/rc.d/S99switch_led boot
 8644 /usr/bin/switch_led
 8758 /usr/bin/tm_shn -b start
 8948 [tntfsiupdated]
 9217 /usr/sbin/smbd -D
 9219 /usr/sbin/nmbd -D
 9264 proftpd: (accepting connections)
 9279 udhcpc -p /var/run/udhcpc-eth0.pid -s /lib/netifd/dhcp.script -O 33 -O 12
 9330 /usr/sbin/minidlnad -f /tmp/minidlna.conf -P /var/run/minidlnad.pid
 9533 /usr/sbin/crond -c /etc/crontabs -l 5
 9568 {dnsproxy_deamon} /bin/sh /usr/lib/dnsproxy/dnsproxy_deamon.sh
 9974 /usr/sbin/improxy -c /etc/improxy.conf -p /tmp/improxy.pid
10122 /usr/sbin/miniupnpd -f /var/etc/miniupnpd.conf
10332 /usr/bin/cloud-brd -c /etc/cloud_config.cfg
10341 /usr/bin/cloud-client
10778 {lic-setup.sh} /bin/sh ./lic-setup.sh
10783 ./gen_lic
11185 {tcd_monitor.sh} /bin/sh ./tcd_monitor.sh
11186 {dc_monitor.sh} /bin/sh ./dc_monitor.sh
11187 {wred-setup.sh} /bin/sh ./wred-setup.sh
11200 ./tcd
11204 ./dcd -i 1800 -p 43200 -S 4 -b
11217 ./wred -B
11241 {clean-cache.sh} /bin/sh ./clean-cache.sh
11244 /usr/bin/tm_shn -t start
15903 sh /lib/deleteTmSigToken.sh 86400
15906 sleep 86400
19612 /usr/sbin/dropbear -P /var/run/dropbear.1.pid -p 22
19771 -ash
19884 sleep 600
21950 sleep 30
22135 sleep 5
22137 sleep 5
22158 sleep 5
22160 sleep 5
```

[as answer  by Hauke Laging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/600989/423992) . Sounds right, I do `mount -a` or `mount /test` and sda2 will be mounted to `/test`  ,  how to  permanently mount with udev rule ?

On my router , I have no idea to run udev rule ( cant find any udev.conf ) , so I test with run script `mount /test` in `/etc/rc.local` , reboot the router but still won't mounted  `/test` 
then I add `sleep 20` for delaying in script and test by reboot the router, and working , automatically mounted /test  now !
Thank you all

Comment: You tell it `nofail` so it won't report if it failed. Maybe take that flag out and see what it says? Also try changing `auto` to `ext4`.

Comment: ok, I changed from auto to ext4, still no luck , where I can see  flag / log fstab ?

Comment: `/var/log/syslog` is usually a good start.

Comment: Can you mount it manually with `mount /test`?

Comment: @PhilipCouling I cant find that syslog in my router, I will look at more details , should be a log why cant be mounted.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I can do mount /dev/sda2  /test ,  however this mount lost if the router rebooted

Comment: Is that system running SystemD? I.e. what is the output of `ps -p 1 -o pid,args`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging, when  did `ps -p 1 -o pid,args`, got return error busybox

Comment: `Usage: ps [-o COL1,COL2=HEADER] [-T] `so I did `ps  -o pid,args` and the result on my edit post above

Comment: Please pretend (assume) that you are explaining your problem to a five-year-old (well, maybe a ten-year-old) over the phone.  Assume that you’re talking to somebody who isn’t in the room with you, so we can’t see your equipment or your screen.  (1) What is `/dev/sda1`?  Is it another partition on the same thumb drive that `/dev/sda2` is on?  Is it a different thumb drive (or some other kind of removable storage)?  Is it a drive (storage device) that’s built into the router?  (2) Can you explain how `/dev/sda1` gets mounted, since it doesn’t appear to be in `/etc/fstab`?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Does your ``df`` output really have two lines beginning `/dev/sda1`?  If so, do you know why?  (Did you do it on purpose?)  If not, please [edit] your question to fix errors.  (4) You say “it [the router/system] will mount automatically `/mnt/sda1`”.  What, exactly, do you mean by that?  Do you mean that the router automatically mounts `/dev/sda1` (on `/mnt/sda1`) when it boots (if `/dev/sda1` is present)?  Do you mean that the router automatically mounts `/dev/sda1` when it is inserted (if `/dev/sda1` is a removable device)? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (5) Which of the above do you want it to do with `/dev/sda2`?  (In other words, when you say “it does not work”, what do you mean by “it”?) (6) Please put [additional] information that’s relevant to the question ***into** the question.*  See my edit for an example, but note that you were asked what happens when you take out the ``nofail`` flag, and whether `mount /test` works, and you didn’t answer those questions. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: P.S. I won’t post this as an answer [yet], because I believe that the question is still unclear, and because I don’t have any way to test it.  But try adding `auto,` to the beginning of the fourth field, so you have ``… /test   ext4   auto,nosuid,nodev,nofail …``.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica', Thank you for your advise and been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On SystemD systems devices listed in `/etc/fstab` which are not present at boot time but appear later are mounted automatically. Other systems don't do that (at least not all of them).

So you need something that triggers a `mount /test` call when the device has become available. This could be done with a udev rule (`RUN=`).

Comment: when I do mount -a after reboot then /dev/sda2  will be mounted  /test , so how to call udev  rule or  can just  script  .sh to do  mount -a and call in etc/rc.local

Comment: on my router , I have no idea to run udev rule ( cant find any udev.conf ) , so I test with run script mount /test in /etc/rc.local , reboot the router but still won't mounted /test  then I add sleep 20 for delaying in script and test by reboot the router, and working , automatically mounted /test now

Comment: @Zoom80 Interesting. Add `blkid >/root/blkid.txt` to `/etc/rc.local` (immediately before the `mount` call.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try:

```
UID=14a0f0f0-27ac-4101-8d11-3057f10d1385  /test errors=remount-ro,user,noatime 0 2
```

that should let any errors show and mount as read-only if there are errors.